# Как вывести и сгруппировать информацию из таблицы

Tags: php, mysql

Есть табличка `news`. в ней столбики `id`, `category`, `text`

```
$res = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM `news` GROUP BY `category` ORDER BY `category` DESC");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res){
    echo $row['category'];
    echo $row['text'];
}
```

`category` выводится, `text` выводится, но если в данной категории больше одного, запрос выводит только один `text`.

Что я делаю не так?

Мне нужно вывести `category` и `text` всех статей соответствующих этой категории, без дублирования category.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
 SELECT
  category,
  GROUP_CONCAT(`text` SEPARATOR ', ') as `text`
FROM `news`
GROUP BY `category` ORDER BY `category` DESC"
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ea41f/189

Однако, помните что GROUP_CONCAT имеет ограничение на максимальную длину в 1024 байта (по умолчанию) [`подробнее тут`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Comment: а как вывести text не через запятую, а с нового абзаца?

Comment: После `SEPARATOR` в кавычках можно указать что угодно. Например, `SEPARATOR '<br>'`